# How to fix 'syntax error: ,' and 'undefined symbol'

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm doing an assignment where I need to declare symbolic constants in MASM along with some other functions in the program. I wrote the whole program and think I did it all properly, but I keep having a syntax error for the symbolic constant declarations. I'm supposed to declare the symbolic constants A = 5120, B=260, C= 170 and D=2200. Under the code directive, with the use of mov instruction, move values of A, B, C and D to EAX, EBX, ECX and EDX respectively. However it keeps saying there's a syntax error for the comma before 'C', that 'C' is a syntax error, and all my other symbolic constants are undefined.

I changed 'C' to 'E' and it worked but I feel like changing the letters isn't the issue here.

```
 .data
 mystring BYTE 20 DUP('a')
 val1 SDWORD 2147483647
 sum DWORD 0
 firstName BYTE "Akash", "Akash", "Akash", "Akash", "Akash"
 firstNameSize = ($ - firstName)
 A = 5120
 B = 260
 C = 170
 D = 2200

 .code
 main proc
 mov eax, A             
 mov ebx, B
 mov ecx, C
 mov edx, D             
 sub ebx, ecx
 add eax, ebx
 sub eax, edx
 mov sum, eax
 invoke ExitProcess,0
```

I expected the output to be that there would be no build errors, the registers would contain the correct values and would do the math on the numbers.

Comment: `C` appears to be a reserved word in MASM.

Comment: Sorry I've only been learning assembly for two weeks, could you explain what a reserved word is?

Comment: Same as in any other language.  In C++ you can't use `int while` or `for` as a variable name because it's a keyword in the language.

Answer (score 3):

C is the name of an operation in MASM, so you can't use it as a variable name.
[Here's](http://www.piclist.com/techref/language/masm/masmAPD.htm) a list of all reserved terms I could find.